# Auto-Open Links From Slack

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, url, hyperlink, slack

I was wondering if anyone knew if it was possible to auto-open links that I receive in Slack.

I work in a call center and every time I get a call, Slackbot gives me a link that I have to click. 100% of the time, the link I receive from Slackbot must be opened.

However, I also know a little JavaScript and was thinking that maybe I could just make a program to do this for me. I was looking into Slack apps, but they don't seem to be too hackable. Anyone have any suggestions or keywords I can Google? I promise I dug through SO and Slack's docs before asking, just wanted to make sure I didn't overlook anything.

Thanks!

Comment: I would maybe look into slacks API: https://api.slack.com/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, this feature currently does not exist. Slack only unfurls URLs, but does not open them.

Its currently also not possible to programmatically change how Slack processes incoming messages, e.g. to create a custom viewer etc. I hope the Slack team add that in the future though. That would be really helpful.

An approach that could work and I would recommend looking into is developing a user script for your browser. Check out [Tampermonkey](https://tampermonkey.net/).

Comment: Okay, not great news but thanks for clarifying. I'll take a look into Tampermonkey. Thanks for your time!

Comment: I did not @rbedger

Comment: Although not what you wanted this is still the best answer I guess. Would be nice if you could mark this as solution so we can close this question. thanks!